# Contour plot of 3 separate Columns, one column for x axis, one for y and the 3rd column is the depth of the contour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contour

I Have a `dataframe` with multiple columns and I need to make a contour plot of `df['A]` as the x axis, `df['B]` as the y axis and `df['C']` as the depth of the contour (z).
So there is no formula to relate x ,y and z but only three separate columns to make a contour plot. they all have the same length.

I have looked up  a lot and I have not yet found anything so I figured to ask this question here.

Comment: People using pandas often use the `matplotlib` module to do this I think.

Comment: yeah but apparently it is not that trivial